# in mysql how can i set a variable with last date and time

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a two variable which will hold yesterday date and time without manually enter date, suppose today date is 26/01/2017 and my variable should hold like

```
declare p_run_from_date datetime;
declare p_run_to_date datetime;

set p_run_from_date = '2016-01-25 00:00:00';
set p_run_to_date = 2016-01-25 23:59:59';
```

Code could be like below but do not know how to set time

```
 set p_run_from_date = ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND

```
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND
```

**Result**

```
CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND  
-------------------------------
2017-01-25 23:59:59
```

So the answer should be

```
set p_run_to_date = (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 SECOND)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should change your logic.  Instead of:

```
where date between p_run_from_date and p_run_to_date
```

or

```
where date >= p_run_from_date and date <= p_run_to_date
```

Use:

```
where date >= p_run_from_date and date < p_run_to_date
```

That inequality makes things much simpler.  And, you don't have to worry about fractions of seconds.

For this:

```
set p_run_from_date = date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 1 day);
set p_run_to_date = CURDATE();
```

I should point out that the answer to your particular question is:

```
set p_run_from_date = date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 1 day);
set p_run_to_date = date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 1 second);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
DATE_ADD(now(), interval -1 day)
```

To your latest question, try this:

```html
TIMESTAMP(DATE(DATE_ADD(now(), interval -1 day)))
```

Comment: how could I set the time like one should be 00:00:00 hh:mm:ss

Comment: Do you care to elaborate, Raymond?

Comment: my date are dynamic but time is static like one  00:00:00 hh:mm:ss and another one should be 23:59:59 hh:mm:ss

Comment: @Hugo Rafael Azevedo.. well i didnt downvote this answer.. but i will elaborate.. topic starter wants to set p_run_to_date to `2016-01-25 23:59:59` as time read "Code could be like below but do not know how to set time set p_run_from_date = ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY )", Using now() can never archive that goal.